# XmlPullParser - How to skip to matching END_TAG?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

```
<root>
    <element> <!-- When this is encountered... -->
        <element>text</element>
        <element>text</element>
        <element>
            <element>text</element>
        </element>
    </element> 
    <element> <!-- ...skip to here. -->
        <element>text</element>
        <element>text</element>
        <element>
            <element>text</element>
        </element>
    </element>
</root>
```

The inner tags may have the same name as the outer tag. In this case they are all called `element`.

Basically, if I am at any given `START_TAG` I want to skip to its corresponding `END_TAG` and continue parsing from the next `START_TAG` at the same depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a snippet on the [Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#skip).

```
 private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Source link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#skip

Comment: Is there also a way to ignore specific tags from being validated, such as `<br>` instead of `</br>` ?